# Duplicated values found in unique indexed column

Tags: mysql, index

I have a database table with an unique index `idx_1(USER_ID, COURSE_ID)`, however I still found some entries with the same `USER_ID` and `COURSE_ID` (both not null). And the other columns of the duplicated rows are not the same. such as `addtime` (default current timestamp), and `updatetime` (default current timestamp on update current timestamp) of the duplicated 2 rows have a difference of 1 second:

```
SELECT * FROM user_course WHERE COURSE_ID='COURSEID1' AND USER_ID='USERID1';

----------------------------------------------------------------
UUID | COURSE_ID | USER_ID | ADDTIME         | UPDATETIME
----------------------------------------------------------------
abc1 |COURSEID1  | USERID1 | 2019-01-01 00:00| 2019-01-01 00:00


SELECT * FROM user_course WHERE UUID='abc1" OR UUID='abc2';

----------------------------------------------------------------
UUID | COURSE_ID | USER_ID | ADDTIME         | UPDATETIME
----------------------------------------------------------------
abc1 |COURSEID1  | USERID1 | 2019-01-01 00:00| 2019-01-01 00:00
----------------------------------------------------------------
abc2 |COURSEID1  | USERID1 | 2019-01-01 00:01| 2019-01-01 00:01
```

when I query the data with `USER_ID` and `COURSE_ID` of one of the duplicated rows, only one row returned, however I can get the rows with duplicated values when query the table with the primary key.

**So my question is:** Is this a bug of MySQL? and how can I avoid this error when working with MySQL?

## server info

**OS:** CentOS 6

**MySQL:** MySQL 5.6

Comment: Did you define your index as unique?. See [13.1.13 CREATE INDEX Syntax :: Unique Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique) and [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fae85cc064cb798162eb6146dd3777ea).

Comment: Are they strings with spaces on the end?

Comment: No, there's no space tailed. When compared with python, the returned value is True. It seems that they are exactly the same.
And the index is unique index.
@Colin'tHart

Comment: Can you post the result of: 
SHOW CREATE TABLE user_course;

Comment: Provide `SELECT HEX(course_id), hex(userid1) FROM ...`

Comment: Hi, I tried as what you recommended, the returned values are exactly the same.